# How to monitor block synchronisation?

Tags: go-ethereum, web3js, synchronization, nodejs

I want to display information about Geth, specifically `eth.getBlock("latest").number`, in a Node.Js GUI. However, I'm not sure how to keep it updated. One solution is to request the information from the browser once every 5 seconds or so, but it doesn't look very elegant. Does web3 provide an event or something like that so that socket.io calls the clients with the updated information whenever a new block is downloaded?

Thanks,

Comment: I was going to answer this can be done using web3.js WebSocket provider and eth_newblockfilter RPC call, but then I did not find any working WebSocket examples or whether filter API supports push over WebSocket.

Answer (score 1):

This was discussed but has not been implemented yet: https://github.com/ethereum/EIPs/issues/51

You can subscribe in the backend to Geth and poll every second and update front end accordingly.